# What is the best verb to use with Termin-booking ,geben oder anbieten oder bieten?

Tags: standard-german

Whats best to say in formal german:

> Können Sie mir bitte einen Termin geben/anbieten/bieten/vorschlagen?

Comment: Whom are you asking? Your doctor's office? Your boss? Your secretary? Your colleage? Someone who applies to work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"bieten" is wrong in this context, the other three are valid though "anbieten" is uncommon.

I would use "geben" if you don't care when the appointment will actually happen (e.g. at the doctor) and "vorschlagen" (suggest) if you might have objections about the date (e.g. business meeting).

Comment: +1, but 'anbieten' is common, too. It expresses more a position of power than 'vorschlagen' does

Comment: @planetmaker To me, 'anbieten' sounds more natural and common coming from the other side: "Ich kann Ihnen den 3.3. anbieten"; not as much when one is (politely) asking for the appointment.

Comment: @marquinho arguably yes. But one could still ask for "Können Sie mir einen Termin in der 25. KW anbieten?"

Comment: @planetmaker Agree – with the specification of a timeframe ("vormittags", "in der 25. KW"...), it works well.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no need, to put the initiative to the other side, so when asking a colleague or a service provider, the following may be appropriate:

> Ich möchte gerne einen Termin für [etwas] vereinbaren
> Ich hätte gerne einen Termin für [etwas] (or even e.g. *Ich hätte gerne einen Kundendienst-Termin*)